# Dock App Bar to top of window in react material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In React material ui, how do you make app bar fixed so that it stays fixed while the rest of the page scrolls?

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if this feature is just new but you don't need the code above. Just add a `position="fixed"` attribute to your `<AppBar />`

```html
return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <AppBar position="fixed">
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
          Title
        </Typography>
        <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  </div>
);
```

Adjusted example from: https://codesandbox.io/s/yw67vxwo69 (demo.js)

Comment: Unfortunately, when you add content to your "demo" so that scrolling is enabled, the Appbar moves up when you scroll and doesn't stay on the screen (aka, docked an accessible wherever you scroll to). No idea why you got upvoted with this answer, but please attempt to correct, as it's wrong and doesn't address what the OP asked.

Comment: @zuckerburg Can you please provide an example? Because last year it worked for me even with content. Don't checked it in the latest version.

Comment: Apologies. I thought your demo.js link was a working version, not a link to reference content you used as a base for your answer

Comment: You're welcome. I will change this later today to make it more readable

Answer (score 3):

Just add a `position: fixed !important;` css (inline or with external css) to your AppBar component. The `!important` is needed if you use external css to force overriding the style defined in material-ui. Don't forget to set `margin-top` to your content because it will get pushed to the top.