# To make a Material-UI div fixed always visible at the top of the page even when page scroll down

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

To make a Material-UI Grid or component fixed always visible at the top of the page even when page scroll down.

Comment: When asking a question, please share some code, so the community will get back with a better answer.

Comment: is this a reactjs or react-native question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **react-sticky** to do this, please check this out [React-sticky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky)

Please check this out [Dock App Bar to top of window in react material ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647661/dock-app-bar-to-top-of-window-in-react-material-ui), I think this Question is already answered here.